# executing multiline terminal python commands during code execution from within code body

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to use some code line speed indicator related libraries such as [**scalene**](https://github.com/plasma-umass/scalene) and [**tamppa**](https://github.com/pra-dan/TAMPPA/blob/master/README.md) to evaluate which code lines consume more times. We will need to run *some command lines in the terminal*, before and after the code execution, for seeing the results. For example using *tamppa* library, if we have the following code (*test.py*) and execute it in PyCharm:

```
from line_profiler import LineProfiler
import random

def do_stuff(numbers):
    s = sum(numbers)
    l = [numbers[i]/43 for i in range(len(numbers))]
    m = ['hello'+str(numbers[i]) for i in range(len(numbers))]

numbers = [random.randint(1,100) for i in range(1000)]
lp = LineProfiler()
lp_wrapper = lp(do_stuff)
lp_wrapper(numbers)
lp.print_stats()
```

I must save the output log by using commands `python test.py > mem_res_1.txt` or `python -m memory_profiler test.py > mem_res_1.txt` in the terminal:

> 1. going to directory -------> cd C:\Users\Ali\Desktop
> 2. saving the output log ----> python -m memory_profiler test.py > mem_res_1.txt

and then import the saved file again to the python code by *tamppa*:

```
from tamppa import mem_parse
mem_parse("mem_res_1.txt")
```

**note:** saving the file could be achieved by *line_profiler* python module `lp.dump_stats("mem_res_1.txt")`, but it is incompatible with *tamppa* and …, and could not be readable by them. I would appreciate any useful recommends to use this module directly (it is not the answer of the issue).

After the code execution and for running one of the aforementioned commands, `C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Local\Temp\test.py>` address is written as default and must be changed to the working **directory** (which contains test.py) i.e. here `C:\Users\Ali\Desktop>`. I think this address could be achieved by `os.getcwd()`, but I don't know how to

1. going to the desired address directory, and then
2. applying the command

**from within python code**, to avoid doing the job manually. I have tried to do so using some codes like:

```
os.system("python -m memory_profiler " + os.getcwd() + r"\test.py" + " > mem_res_1.txt")
```

which will shows:

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another
> process.

It is good to say that if I use `C:\Users\Ali\Desktop` directly, in one step, in the terminal command as `python -m memory_profiler C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\test.py > mem_res_1.txt`, it will save that file in the ex temp folder.
I know these codes are half-baked and wrong here, but I guess, perhaps, they must be used for this question in a correct way.
I would be appreciated for any help to run these terminal command codes from within the python code execution, *if it is possible of course*.

One line code is more interested.

Comment: i believe there is something called pybash that lets you execute bash commands in python..

Comment: @ChristopherHoffman I see that, thanks. I think it could be handled, as `pybash`, by built-in python modules e.g. `os.system` or `subprocess`. The issue is related to going to the `.py` file containing address firstly, as mentioned, and then the other codes.

Comment: I don't know the workings of scalene and tampaa, i would read the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> note: saving the file could be achieved by line_profiler python module
> lp.dump_stats("mem_res_1.txt"), but it is incompatible with tamppa and
> …, and could not be readable by them.

A solution for using `lp.dump_stats` output together with `tamppa` is presented in a related [line_profiler issue](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler/issues/117#issuecomment-1019808659).

For the aforementioned terminal default address problem, perhaps it could be handled by a symbolic link in that directory pointing to the containing folder, which is mentioned in [one of PyCharm issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-52683).
There are some [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406887/subprocess-changing-directory)s that have [valuable answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744473/command-line-execution-in-different-folder) help to change directory from within the code body. With inspiration from them and relating to the aforementioned libraries, the following `subprocess` codes can run the needed terminal commands from within the code body (applicable):

```
subprocess.getoutput("python -m memory_profiler test.py > mem_res.txt")  # tamppa
subprocess.call("python -m scalene --on test.py", stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)  # scalene
```

In my tests, these codes detect the working directory, automatically, but could use `cwd=os.getcwd()` subprocess method to ensure returning current working directory of the process, if any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about all these fancy python tools.  It's all already built into bash.  Install bash on Ubuntu on Windows here.  And I will give you the script to run.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows-download-now-3/

```
#!/bin/bash
#Start time
START=$(date +%s)
$(python module.py)
#Call more stuff
END=$(date +%s)

#End time
DIFFERENCE=$(( END - START ))
echo 
echo Time Elapsed: $DIFFERENCE seconds.
```

Comment: The answer is helpful but is not the desired one. The aim is to use terminal in my code to handle from within the PyCharm or …. So, I could evaluate the results when I'm running and debugging my main code; not additional works to do or with another tool. **I'm seeking a pythonic way**, which I think it is possible. Where did you apply your codes, on terminal, cmd, or PowerShell? I didn't understand how it works on my codes.

Comment: As it is mentioned in the link it needs to have near latest build of windows 10 64-bit, which is a limitation for me. I would not update the windows to avoiding probable adverse problems on my heavy daily simulations. I have tried to install it on my another system, but I couldn't do so and faced to some issues. I have tried [some methods](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-windows-subsystem-for-linux-has-no-installed-distributions-error/) on the internet and some [other SO links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44829878/trying-to-use-bash-on-windows-and-got-no-installed-distributions-message)

Comment: Besides the aforementioned comments, I mention that I used `line_profiler` to evaluate consuming time by **each** line of the code, not just the running time of the total code  which could be achieved by importing `time` in the code. I guess your code will determine this total code execution time, not line by line evaluation.

Comment: Found this on google - https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html